# batch filed does not recognise and run the second (next) command

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, anaconda

My batch file does not recognise or run the second command after I have changed the windows command prompt to anaconda prompt. It changes to anconda environment but does not run the python file.

I tried using & and && but that does not work. I also tried using call before each command but that does not work either

here is the batch file

```
%windir%\System32\cmd.exe "/K" C:\Users\rexon.carvalho\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\Users\rexon.carvalho\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3 

python C:\Users\rexon.carvalho\Jypyter_scripts\pjm_load\cron_test.py

pause
```

here is the output

as shown in the command prompt

```
C:\Users\rexon.carvalho\Desktop>C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe "/K" C:\Users\rexon.carvalho\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\Users\rexon.carvalho\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3

(base) C:\Users\rexon.carvalho\Desktop>
```

Comment: Have you tried opening a `cmd.exe` window, entering `cmd /?` and reading the usage information? If you have, I'd be interested to know where you found `"/K"`. I would suggest instead using `/K "your command"`. You may also note, upon entering `set` in the same window, that you can shorten `C:\Users\rexon.carvalho\AppData\Local` with `%LocalAppData%`.

Comment: `/K` as a switch to `CMD.EXE` causes the subshell to stay open after executing the command passed as a parameter. Are you sure that this is what you want? Most of the time, when a batch file is called by another, the switch desired is `/C` instead.

Comment: Is your `python` command is supposed to run in the same window, you opened in the previous line? or were you supposed to `Call "%LocalAppData%\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat" "%LocalAppData%\Continuum\anaconda3"`?

Comment: You all are right!, I deleted the cmd.exe and now it works. Thanks!. so the new bat file is ```call C:\Users\rexon.carvalho\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\Users\rexon.carvalho\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3

call python C:\Users\rexon.carvalho\Jypyter_scripts\pjm_load\cron_test.py


pause```

Comment: You probably don't need to use `Call` for the `Python` command. **1.** `Call "%LocalAppData%\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat" "%LocalAppData%\Continuum\anaconda3"`, **2.** `python "%UserProfile%\Jypyter_scripts\pjm_load\cron_test.py"`, **3.** `Pause`.

Comment: This exact topic has been covered a couple of times already this year.

Comment: Executing a batch file transfer control from one batch to another, the first batch file exits. You use `call` to say you want to wait for the other batch to return. Using `call` with an exe doesn't do anything different so it is unnecessary and breaches the principal of simplicity.